# Blob storage java sdk authorize by azure AD

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

Do we have any way BlobServiceClient with Azure AD infomation(username/password).
Here is code im using for connectionString but i cannot find any function for AD:

`new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this. But you can use clientId,clientSecret and tenantId to generate credential, then connect to blob storage.

Code Snippet:

```
ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .tenantId(tenantId)
        .build();

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().credential(clientSecretCredential).endpoint(endpoint).buildClient();
```

API document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclientbuilder?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, cause i'm referring  the Micrisoft Azure Storage Explorer tools, they provide for us that options.